# How to send multiple emails by php variable in Addcc

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

From $list i am getting all the emails that are posted by form after using explode

```
$list = explode(',', $guest_email);



    foreach ($list as $k => $v) {

        $mail = new PHPmailer();
        $mail->From = $smtp_user;
        $mail->FromName = $fromname;
        $mail->Mailer   = "mail";
        $mail->Subject = "";
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        //$mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = ;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = '';
        $mail->Host = $smtp;
        $mail->Port = $port;

        $mail->Password = $sm;
        $mail->Username = $sm;

        $mail->Body = $bodyContent;
```

in below line the mail are going to all posted email address, in next line i want to add all the emails in cc, but it is not working

```
$mail->AddAddress($v);
$mail->Addcc($v)
$mail->AddReplyTo($smtp_user);

if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
}
```

how to send all email in $mail->Addcc($v)

Comment: Why are you using both addAddress and addCc with the same address? That's pointless. Read the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: i want to use first email as a to and rest of the mail in cc, how it is possible please tell us.

Comment: You're making a new instance every time around the loop, so all your addresses are cleared. Look at the mailing list example - see that it sets things up before the loop. You will need to do something similar, just with only addCC inside the loop.